# How to assign an array of objects to an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object and array of objects the later is a server array and the first one is a reference object that I want to use to get the values that I want from the main array and idea how to intigrate the array in to the object ? I tried to use Object.assign but no luck.

```js
const obj1 = { day1: ['cake', 'muffin'], day2: ['grapes']};
const arrObj2: = [{name : 'cake', group 'dessert'},{name : 'muffin', group 'dessert'},{name : 'grapes', group 'vegs'}]
// Expected results 
const newObject = //{ 
                  //  day1: [{name : 'cake', group 'dessert'},{name : 'muffin', group 'dessert'}]
                  //, day2: [{name : 'grapes', group 'vegs'}]
                  //};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `.reduce` to map thru all entries `[key, value]` from`obj1` and then filter items from `arrObj2` where `name` is in your `value` array

```js
const newObject = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((p, [key, value]) => ({
  ...p,
  [key]: arrObj2.filter(f => value.includes(f.name))
}), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()`:

```js
const obj1 = { day1: ['cake', 'muffin'], day2: ['grapes']};
const arrObj2 = [{name : 'cake', group: 'dessert'},{name : 'muffin', group: 'dessert'},{name : 'grapes', group: 'vegs'}];
// Expected results 
const newObj = {
  day1: arrObj2.filter((el) => obj1.day1.includes(el.name)),
  day2: arrObj2.filter((el) => obj1.day2.includes(el.name))
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not a valid Javascript. There should not be a colon after the variable name. I recommend you to learn about variables and loops in programming.

But to your answer, just loop through data and replace values:

```
for(var day in obj1) 
    for(var i=0; i<obj1[day].length; i++) 
        for(var j=0; j<arrObj2.length; j++) 
            if(obj1[day][i]==arrObj2[j].name) obj1[day][i]=arrObj2[j];
```

I think you should represent "arrObj2" as an object (string-to-string map).

```
var GroupMap = {"cake":"dessert","muffin":"desert","grapes":"vegs"};
```

Comment: I think you should know at this point that nested loops are very bad, and I suggest you learn more about time time complexity.

Comment: I am using typescript on src-code so I forgot the the colon.

Comment: @Richardson You should learn about time complexity. All these "filter" / "reduce" / "include" methods just loop through arrays in linear time. "includes" inside "filter" inside "reduce" are three nested loops.